# Multiple select from one row from A table and insert result as multiple rows in B table and repeat in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need insert data from static table to table with multiple custom options, so it looks like below.

A table:

```
+------+------+--------+-------+
| name | type | weight | color |
+------+------+--------+-------+
|   1  |    A |    10  | green |
+------+------+--------+-------+
|   2  |    B |     3  | blue  |
+------+------+--------+-------+
|   3  |    D |     9  | gold  |
+------+------+--------+-------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------+-------------+--------------+
| name | option_name | option_value |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 1    | type        | A            |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 1    | weight      | 10           |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 1    | color       | green        |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 2    | type        | B            |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 2    | weight      | 3            |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 2    | color       | blue         |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 3    | type        | D            |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 3    | weight      | 9            |
+------+-------------+--------------+
| 3    | color       | gold         |
+------+-------------+--------------+
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross join trick to "UNPIVOT" the values:

```
select 
    t.name,
    case x.i 
        when 1 then 'type'
        when 2 then 'weight'
        when 3 then 'color'
    end option_name,
    case x.i
        when 1 then type
        when 2 then cast(weight as char(50))
        when 3 then color
    end option_value
from your_table t
cross join (
    select 1 i union all
    select 2 i union all
    select 3 i
) x
```

`cast(weight as char(50))` is required for weight because the data types need to be consistent and weight is (probably) a numeric column and needs to be converted into string.

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82b7ae2/1)